# Having models from two apps sorted in /admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I noticed that the Django `/admin/` site shows me a list of models, grouping them by the apps they come from. How can I make this list include another app?

Comment: This is very unclear. Models are sorted by their app; a project is equivalent to a site, one project can't include models from another one unless the apps are installed in both.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I replaced "project" with "app" then. Could you undo your close vote?

Comment: Well, it's still not clear what you mean. If you know how to register models from some apps in the admin, what is the problem with registering additional ones?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: looks like you just answered the question - I needed to know that I need to register them within one app's admin.py. Thanks ;)

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Feel invited to post this as your answer.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, why downvote? He wants to "merge" apps so that all models appear in one place.  I don't know the answer, but I guess the sites app would be the place to start looking and replace what it is doing with custom behavior.

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a custom view linking to the admin pages, but I gues breadcrumbs and things may not work.

Comment: @wobbily_col: Actually, DanielRoseman answered it - it looks like registering the models in admin.py is enough.

Comment: Its the downvote that bothered me, not the answer.